# Find the values of $b$ for which the equation $2\log_{\frac{1}{25}}(bx+28)=-\log_5(12-4x-x^2)$ has only one solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, quadratics

Find the values of 'b' for which the equation

$$2\log_{\frac{1}{25}}(bx+28)=-\log_5(12-4x-x^2)$$ has only one solution.
=$$-2/2\log_{5}(bx+28)=-\log_5(12-4x-x^2)$$
My try:

After removing the logarithmic terms I get the quadratic $x^2+x(b+4)+16=0$
Putting discriminant equal to $0$ I get $b={4,-12}$
But $-12$ cannot be a solution as it makes $12-4x-x^2$ negative so I get $b=4$ as the only solution.

But the answer given is $(-\infty,-14]\cup{4}\cup[14/3,\infty)$.I've no idea how. Help me please.

Comment: You can't remove the logarithmic term like that, the bases aren't the same.

Comment: I adjusted the bases before removing @ZainPatel.Check.

Comment: Because there is a root that should be ignored.

Comment: Which root? @ZackNi

Comment: the root of quadratic equation which makes the item in the parentheses of the logarithm negative.

Comment: Have you considered this case?

Comment: @ZackNi -_- read the question....

Comment: I have read it. It shows that you only consider the discriminant equals to 0 but not the case that there are two real roots and one should be ignored.

Comment: Ok now I get you @ZackNi....sorry for the "-_-" face.You are right.I get my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$x^2+(4+b)x+16=0\tag1$$
This is correct.

However, note that when we solve
$$2\log_{\frac{1}{25}}(bx+28)=-\log_5(12-4x-x^2)$$
we have to have
$$bx+28\gt 0\quad\text{and}\quad 12-4x-x^2\gt 0,$$
i.e.
$$bx\gt -28\quad\text{and}\quad -6\lt x\lt 2\tag2$$

Now, from $(1)$, we have to have $(4+b)^2-4\cdot 16\geqslant 0\iff b\leqslant -12\quad\text{or}\quad b\geqslant 4$.

**Case 1** : $b\lt -14$

$$(2)\iff -6\lt x\lt -\frac{28}{b}$$

Let $f(x)=x^2+(4+b)x+16$. Then, since the equation has only one solution, we have to have
$$f(-6)f\left(-\frac{28}{b}\right)\lt 0\iff b\lt -14$$
So, in this case, $b\lt -14$.

**Case 2** : $-14\leqslant b\leqslant -12$ or $4\leqslant b\lt \frac{14}{3}$

$$(2)\iff -6\lt x\lt 2$$

$b=4$ is sufficient, and $b=-12$ is not sufficient. For $b\not=4,-12$,
$$f(-6)f(2)\lt 0\iff b\lt -14\quad\text{or}\quad b\gt \frac{14}{3}$$
So, in this case, $b=4$.

**Case 3** : $b\geqslant \frac{14}{3}$

$$(2)\iff -\frac{28}{b}\lt x\lt 2$$
$b=\frac{14}{3}$ is sufficient. For $b\gt\frac{14}{3}$,
$$f\left(-\frac{28}{b}\right)f(2)\lt 0\iff b\gt \frac{14}{3}$$
So, in this case, $b\geqslant 14/3$.

Therefore, the answer is $$\color{red}{(-\infty,-14)\cup{4}\cup\bigg[\frac{14}{3},\infty\bigg)}$$

Comment: Don't have to do so much.Just f(-6)f(2)<0 ensures there is exactly one real root between the valid bound's of x...

Comment: @ZOZ: $f(-6)f(2)\lt 0$ enables us to eliminate the case where there are two real roots, but if we only consider $f(-6)f(2)\lt 0$, it is possible that there is no real roots in the interval where $bx+28\gt 0$ and $-6\lt x\lt 2$.

Comment: I get your comment.But I still have difficulty in understanding the cases into which you divided the problem.Like Why did you take the first case as b<-14 ?

Comment: @ZOZ: We have $-6, 2$ and $-28/b$ as the endpoints of the intervals we are interested in. Now, $-14$ comes from $b$ such that $2=-28/b$. Also, $14/3$ comes from $-6=-28/b$. I hope this helps.

Comment: @ZOZ: I just compared $2$ with $-28/b$, and $-6$ with $-28/b$. As a result, we have $-14,-12,4$ and $14/3$ as the endpoints of the intervals on $b$, so I separate it into three cases.

Comment: Don't you think there must be open bracket on ${{-14,\frac{14}{3}}}$?

Comment: @mathophile : Thanks. You are right that $b=-14$ has to be excluded, but $b=\frac{14}{3}$ has to be included since $x=-\frac 83$ is the only solution.

Comment: @mathophile : You have just asked [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4353775/if-equation-logx22ax-log4x-4a-13-has-only-one-solution-then-exhaustiv). I think that your new question can be solved in the way I solved this question here. Why don't you try that?

Comment: Yes, I tried to solve this question as you did. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

> > Find the values of 'b' for which the equation $$2\log_{\frac{1}{25}}(bx+28)=-\log_5(12-4x-x^2)\tag1$$ has only one solution.
>
> After removing the logarithmic terms I get the quadratic $$x^2+x(b+4)+16=0\tag2$$

$$(1)\iff\ln(\text{b}x+28)=\ln(12-4x-x^2)\\\iff x^2+x(b+4)+16=0\quad\text{and}\quad bx+28>0\\\iff x=-\frac b2-2\pm\frac12\sqrt{(b+12)(b-4)}\quad\text{and}\quad x>-\frac{28}b.$$

> Putting discriminant equal to $0$ I get $b={4,-12}$
> But $-12$ cannot be a solution as it makes $12-4x-x^2$ negative so **I get $b=4$ as the only solution**.

You forgot to consider the case in which equation $(2)$ has two distinct roots exactly one of which satisfies $(1).$ From the above equivalences, this corresponds to $$-\frac b2-2-\frac12\sqrt{(b+12)(b-4)}\le -\frac{28}b\quad\text{and}\quad -\frac b2-2+\frac12\sqrt{(b+12)(b-4)}>-\frac{28}b,$$ whose solution, [according to Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iima5fx9p1), is $$\left(-\infty,-14\right]\cup\left[\frac{14}3,\infty\right).$$

Combining the two cases gives $$\left(-\infty,-14\right]\cup\{4\}\cup\left[\frac{14}3,\infty\right),$$ as required.